# How to pass data in ASP.NET MVC without showing it in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm try to pass data like json or something from a view to another controller. I can pass data in the url but then it shows my data.

I try to use `ViewBag` but it is not as efficient as I want, because that can be read at developer mode.

```
http://localhost:53270/Link/showPage?noPhone=0812********
```

Comment: To pass anything from your View to your Controller - you need a request (AJAX for example)

Comment: Use POST method of HTTP

Comment: Can you explain more about your specific use case? There are ways to get around this like using a POST request instead of a GET request. But that can be read by developers?

Comment: @xRavisher i try use RedirectToAction() method to pass data into another view but in that url show my data like "http://localhost:53270/Link/showPage?noPhone=081211917717". And how to hide my data?

Comment: You could use a form, Html.beginform etc. Really depends on your case as mentioned above are you wanting to post the data on page load or after the user does something?

Comment: @emert117 i want to try to avoid use ajax or post like that, i mean like that my last choice. i mean if asp.net have some feature or method that can pass the data safely maybe that will be great :)

Comment: ASP.NET has ViewState, which more or less does what you're after, but that's a WebForms technology; the MVC Framework is intended to work _with_ HTTP, so passing values via a query string is normal and expected. Otherwise, your only other option is Session, but you want to avoid over-using it.

Comment: POST or Cookie are likely what you want to use. Can you talk us through what is the issue with having the data in the URL like that?

Comment: `can be read at developer mode` you've said it, `developer mode` which meant to be for `developer`. if you want to rewrite the url, you can route the url mapping from within the code (url routing). which can be used to rewrite the url to be something like this `http://localhost:53270/Link/081211917717` or even this `http://localhost:53270/Link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can post your data to the target controller using Form.
2. You can make an AJAX call to post the data.

But remember in the both cases you need to make a 'POST' call because 'GET' would be visible to user in browser link.

3. Or You can encrypt the data before sending it in the Url and then decrypt it on the other controller.

Or

You can try Session or ViewData.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: how about i want to pass my data to another view
i have try return RedirectToAction("showPageOTP", "Link", new { nohp = sample.nohp, token });
but url show in my browser

Comment: there can be more possibilities you can set your data temporarily in the localStorage using javascript and you can get when required especially in case of token.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
    // At View

    @html.textbox("noPhone"); 


    // At Controller
    string name = Request["noPhone"];
```